# How does MT19937RNG generate a random number less than 32 bit?

Tags: python, random, cryptography

We know that the `random` module in python use MT19937 to generate a 32-bit random number, for example:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(123)
>>> random.getrandbits(32)
224899942L
>>> random.getrandbits(32)
1149664691L
>>> random.getrandbits(32)
374463918L
>>> random.getrandbits(32)
3302642556L
```

The output is the same as the MT19937's output when I set the same seed.

However, if I want to generate a random number less than 32-bit, for example, if I want to use random.getrandbits(1) to generate a 1-bit random number, at first I thought the result is just `random.getrandbits(32)&1`, but when I put into practice, I found it's not so:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(123)
>>> random.getrandbits(1)
0L
>>> random.getrandbits(1)
0L
>>> random.getrandbits(1)
0L
>>> random.getrandbits(1)
1L
```

Now I have no idea why the output become `0,0,0,1...`, Where do these numbers come from?

And as we all know, if we get 624 consecutive 32-bit random numbers generated by MT19937RNG, we can easily recover the seed and calculate any random number, but if we can only get consecutive random numbers less than 32-bit like 1-bit, can we still break the MT19937RNG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the output of `random.getrandbits(1)` become 0,0,0,1..., Where do these numbers come from?

These are the high-order bits of the results of `random.getrandbits(32)`. Just look at the [source](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.1/Python-3.8.1.tgz) in file `Modules/_randommodule.c`

```
if (k <= 32)  /* Fast path */
    return PyLong_FromUnsignedLong(genrand_int32(self) >> (32 - k));
```

> if we can only get consecutive random numbers less than 32-bit like 1-bit, can we still break the MT19937RNG?

Yes. Of course we need 32 times more values. Basically, we take the 19937 bits of the state as unknowns, write one linear equation of these variables for each bit that we know, and solve.